Using javascript to transform/manipulate data in google cloud dataform (sqlx)
im trying to use a javascript function to test if i can manipulate data in dataform from a query, however compilator says that "color" is not defined (one of the fields im trying to manipulate), I have not been able to find any example on how to do use the functions, only seen examples with js constants but not data manipulation, here is how I am trying (notice when im calling the function "addcolor" on the query SELECT):
config {
    type: "view",
    name: "available_bicycles_dataform"
}

SELECT
  ab.bicycle_id,
  ab.manufacturer,
  ab.color as color,
  ${addcolor(color)} AS added_color
FROM
  `learn-project.bicycles.available_bicycles` AS ab
LEFT JOIN
  `learn-project.bicycles_scheduled.scheduled_job_used_bicycles` AS abdf
ON
  ab.bicycle_id = abdf.bike_id
WHERE
  abdf.bike_id IS NULL


js {
    function addcolor(color) {
        return color + "hi";
    }
}

EDIT:
Adding an example of what I would expect to happen or trying to achieve:
Suppose I have the following data in the available_bicycles table:



bicycle_id
manufacturer
color




1
ACME
Blue


2
ACME
Red


3
ACME
Green



what I would expect dataform to do when running the query for creating the view available_bicycles_dataformis to add a new column which is the one "manipulated" with the javascript function:



bicycle_id
manufacturer
color
added_color




1
ACME
Blue
Bluehi


2
ACME
Red
Redhi


3
ACME
Green
Greenhi



notice the new added_color column which appended "hi" to the color

The way I think of Dataform and JavaScript is that the JavaScript is executed during compile time when the SQLX is compiled to pure SQL.  Do not think that the JS is executed during BigQuery execution of the SQL statements.  With that in mind, we look at your SELECT statement and see:
SELECT
  ab.bicycle_id,
  ab.manufacturer,
  ab.color as color,
  ${addcolor(color)} AS added_color
FROM ...

Focusing on the line which reads:
${addcolor(color)} AS added_color

I interpret this as ....

Our goal is to generate SQL ... we are going to have SQL that reads:

SELECT
  ab.bicycle_id,
  ab.manufacturer,
  ab.color as color,


and now we come across ${addcolor(color)}.  What we will do here is invoke a JavaScript function called addcolor and what it returns will be subsituted in place for the SQL component.  So if that function returns "HelloWorld", it would be as though we coded:

SELECT
  ab.bicycle_id,
  ab.manufacturer,
  ab.color as color,
  HelloWorld
FROM ...


Since your JS functionc called addcolor() took a parameter and the parameter value you provided was color, during compilation, the compiler tried to resolve the parameter as a variable called color but there was no such variable in scope.  This explains your error message of:
"color" is not defined

Later ... after your edit ...
We must now ask ourselves, what do we want our resulting SQL to look like ... the answer would then be:
SELECT
  ab.bicycle_id,
  ab.manufacturer,
  ab.color as color,
  CONCAT(ab.color, "hi") AS added_color
FROM ...

In this case, there is no need for a JS function call.
However, if what you need is to perform logic within a JavaScript function, you would created a named User Defined Function (UDF).  The documentation for this can be found here.  The documentation contains samples/examples and feels quite straightforward to digest ... however, in summary:
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION myJsFunc(input)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js
AS r"""
  return input + "hi!";
"""

Your invocation logic in your SQL statement would then become:
SELECT
  ab.bicycle_id,
  ab.manufacturer,
  ab.color as color,
  myJsFunc(ab.color) AS added_color
FROM ...

What I want you to notice is that nothing in this story requires Dataform.  Rather, the definition of a UDF is itself a SQL statement and the invocation of the UDF is merely a reference to the previously defined UDF.  Where Dataform provides you capability is in managing all of these SQL statements but does not provide any function during the execution of those statements when run.

Hey thanks for answering, so if I execute it, it should work (havent tried yet because of the console compiler error)? or if you know the correct way to use the js to transform the query fields I appreciate

You haven't described what you are trying to achieve ... only that there was a compilation error.  So I can't respond to "it should work".  If you want to perform a transformation of the value of data at runtime using JavaScript then the right way would be to create a UDF coded in JS and invoke the UDF.  Dataform is for describing the SQL you want to execute and says/adds nothing to the semantic processing of the SQL when it is submitted to BigQuery for execution.

Maybe I was not very clear, just added an edit of what im trying to achieve with it

I have updated the original answer with more text based on your edits.

Okay I understand that it is possible to get the desired result the way you mentioned, but if I needed to use a js function to achieve the same result, how would it be done?

I have added more text in the previously posted answer.
